# jquery on-method excluding children

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to exclude a child element from the on-method. I've this code at the moment:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toBuyItem', function() {
    if($(this).has('.itemComment').length != 0){
        $(this).addClass("toggling");
        toggle(".toggling .itemComment");
        $(this).removeClass("toggling"); 
    }
}).on('click','.done',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(this).parent().removeClass("toBuyItem");
    $(this).parent().addClass("boughtItem");
    $("#boughtItems").prepend($(this).parent());
});
```

".done" is a child of ".toBuyItem" so I need to exclude it from the first on. How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look at event.stopPropagation(), https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 1):

Use `stopPropagation` on `.done` click event.

```
$(document).on('click', '.toBuyItem', function() {
    if($(this).has('.itemComment').length != 0){
        $(this).addClass("toggling");
        toggle(".toggling .itemComment");
        $(this).removeClass("toggling"); 
    }
}).on('click','.done',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(this).parent().removeClass("toBuyItem");
    $(this).parent().addClass("boughtItem");
    $("#boughtItems").prepend($(this).parent());
});
```

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitely exclude it using:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toBuyItem', function(e){
            if($(e.target).hasClass('done')) return;
            if($(this).has('.itemComment').length != 0){
                $(this).addClass("toggling");
                toggle(".toggling .itemComment");
                $(this).removeClass("toggling"); 
            }          
    })
```

Comment: they all have the class "done". it's just that if I click on done then it should do something else...

Comment: So use the check to do something else. That's said, you should provide relevant HTML in question itself with expected behaviour so your question would be clearer